# MenuItem is returning null

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-modules

I am developing titanium android module for chromecast for this I am trying to create a menu bar.
Below code is I am using for creating the menu:

```
protected Menu newMenuInstance(Context context) {
    try {
        Class <? > menuBuilderClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder");
        Constructor <? > constructor = menuBuilderClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class);

        return (Menu) constructor.newInstance(context);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now, I am inflating menu bar by the below code:

```
@Kroll.method
public void castButtonLoader() {

    Menu menu = newMenuInstance(TiApplication.getAppCurrentActivity());

    Log.i("menu ", "Menu instance created " + menu);
    int menuId = TiApplication.getAppRootOrCurrentActivity()
        .getResources()
        .getIdentifier("main", "menu",
    TiApplication.getInstance().getPackageName());
    Log.i("menu ID", "Menu id get =" + menuId);

    MenuInflater inflater = TiApplication.getAppCurrentActivity()
        .getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(menuId, menu);

    MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem;

    mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(menuId);
    Log.i("MediaRoute ", " Media route menu item ref =" + mediaRouteMenuItem);
    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
    Log.i("MediaRouteActionProvider ", " MediaRouteActionProvider ref =" + mediaRouteActionProvider);
    // Set the MediaRouteActionProvider selector for device discovery.
    mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);

}
```

Now, on the MenuItem, it is returning null. Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use the MenuBuilder from the AppCompat library as that is what Titanium uses as well. Did you try that?